# Run a script file as administrator

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, batch-file, command-prompt

I have this .vbs script that I am trying to run on windows 7. 
It has to run with full permissions and it has to do it automatically. 
To be clear When the user double clicks on the file it will get the prompt that asks "to allow to run the file as an administrator", and then run with full permissions.

To do this I created a batch file (run.bat) that calls the script file

```
cscript "V02.vbs"
pause
```

then I created a shortcut for the batch file which I can choose to run as admin.

The problem I encounter now is that when I run the batch file as admin the folder changes to c\windows\system32. The script, batch file and shortcut are all in the same folder. is there a way to get the folder location?

Comment: in your shortcut do you set the `start In` property?

Comment: start in points to the folder that contains the files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood...

The easiest solution would be to "hardcode" that path into the patch file with a -
cd \path\to\my\script
cscript myscript.vbs
pause

Comment: that works, but this folder will be sent to different users. It needs to be in such a way that irrespective to were the user saves it, a user opens the folder , double clicks on the shortcut and it works.

Comment: Create a batch file that the user runs first.  Let's say setup.bat - inside of that batch file, get the current working directory and insert it into the script.  You could then use this method to dynamically run-as-admin - http://www.insidethe.com/blog/2009/12/how-to-launch-a-wsh-vbscript-as-administrator-in-windows-7-and-vista/

Answer (score 1):

Use "[modifiers with batch parameters](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx)". From the linked documentation:

> %~dp1 Expands %1 to a drive letter and path.

Since `%0` is your script, `%~dp0` is what you want:

```
cscript "%~dp0V02.vbs"
pause
```

Note that %~dp0 includes the trailing backslash, so your v02.vbs file name above becomes quite hard to read.